# Divide dictionary value(s) by integer value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with only one entry (key names are varying and I don't know them) and want to divide the value by another integer value.

Since `dict.values()` only delivers dict views which were not suitable for a division, my workaround was to convert the dictionary value into a list and getting the element by its index:

```
in_max = {'b_el': 100000}
soc_max = 700000
c_rate_in = [in_max[k] for k in in_max][0] / soc_max

print(c_rate_in)
0.14285714285714285
```

But this solution seems to be a bit heavy-handed to me and also does not look very nice.

Is there a smarter way to get the same result?

Comment: If there is only one entry, why not just use `in_max['b_el']`?

Comment: PS: I know that I could also access the dict element by its key. But the difficutly is that the keys may vary and I don't know their names..

Comment: Wow, you were faster.. ;-)

Comment: I'll add it to my question..

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen that this already had been asked for. `next(iter(in_max.values()))` did the job for me!